# Integrate AFNetworking AFXMLRequestOperation into my own method with block completion callback

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking

I am using the `AFXMLRequestOperation` method of the wonderful `AFNetworking`. What I would like to use is use the following, but wrap my own method around it, with my own completion callback.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.groups.browse&api_key=b6300e17ad3c506e706cb0072175d047&cat_id=34427469792%40N01&format=rest"]];
AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
  XMLParser.delegate = self;
  [XMLParser parse];
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
+ (void)makeRequestWithURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
        XMLParser.delegate = self;
        [XMLParser parse];
    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];

    if (completion) {
        // How can I call my cometion block when AFXMLRequestOpersation is finished?
    }

}
```

Then call it using:

```
[MyClass makeRequestWithURL:url completion^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            NSLog(@"AFNetworking Finished");
        }
}];
```

Can can I know when `AFNetworking` has finished in MY completion block?

Comment: What is finished supposed to represent - success or failure?

Comment: Suppose to represent success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your completion block in the success block:

```
+ (void)makeRequestWithURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
        XMLParser.delegate = self;
        [XMLParser parse];
        // call completion block here
        if (completion) {
          completion(YES);
        }

    } failure:nil];
    [operation start];
}
```

You should also implement the failure block of `AFXMLRequestOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the completion block will be run regardless of the result with the BOOL showing success/failure it would need to look like this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
  XMLParser.delegate = self;
  [XMLParser parse];

  if (completion) {
    completion(YES);
  }

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParse) {

  if (completion) {
    completion(NO);
  }

}];
[operation start];
```